# Opening a link in an external browser, but not the one set as default

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web

I use Opera as my default browser but use Chrome just as often - I just use two separate browsers for two separate groups of tasks.

If I want to open a URL in Opera, my default browser, it's very simple:

```
Process.Start("https://www.google.com")
```

However, what if I want to open a URL in a non-default browser, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Process.Start("iexplore", "https://www.google.com")
```

That would open the URL in IE, regardless of the default browser.  You would need to specify the EXE file path for your preferred browser in the same way.